# Trouble accessing google-maps on android

Tags: android, google-maps, gradle, android-studio

I have an app that recently migrated to android studio with gradle from eclipse. The app is existing on Play Store.

I just took over the project and I get and error when trying too run it on my device.

The error I get is

```
10-07 11:06:45.267  24320-24452/com.packet.***** D/REQUEST﹕ Connection opened       to:https://clients4.google.com/glm/mmap/api
10-07 11:06:45.267  24320-24452/com.packet.***** D/REQUEST﹕ Open Connection
10-07 11:06:45.327  24320-24452/com.packet.***** D/REQUEST﹕ DRD(46): 62|147
10-07 11:06:45.327  24320-24452/com.packet.***** D/REQUEST﹕ Close
10-07 11:06:45.327  24320-24452/com.packet.***** D/REQUEST﹕ Error processing: com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.b.d@<key>not retrying
10-07 11:06:45.337  24320-24452/com.packet.***** D/REQUEST﹕ Retrying: com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.c.au@<key>
```

All credentials is set in the manifest file and nothing has changed, since last build on Eclipse.

Has it something to do with debug.keystore? My search through internet has somehow concluded to that, but I cant figure it out.

Any help appriciated.

Comment: Did u try running on eclipse as you developed from that IDE?

Answer (score 0):

The solutions is to use the `debug.keystore` used on the development machine. I contacted the developer and I obtained it from him.